# setOutputKeyComparator - Mapreduce Secondary Sort (After ValueGrouping)

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce, key, grouping

I am just trying hands on with Mapreduce program on AskUbuntu dataset.

My mapper output is

**Syntax**

```
Key: TAG-<TAG_NAME>-<PARAM>  Value: <PARAM>-<Count>
```

**Example:**

```
Key - TAG-windows-QUE Value - QUE-1241
Key - TAG-windows-VIEWS Value - VIEWS-4369
Key - TAG-windows-QUE Value - QUE-1
Key - TAG-windows-VIEWS Value - VIEWS-1
```

I am partitioning it based on the first three characters of key using **Partitioner**. 
ie. TAG

Also i am using **ValueGroupingComparator** to group set of values 
ie. TAG-windows

```
public static class ValueGroupingComparator implements RawComparator<Text> {

        /*value grouping comparator will group by the first few letters of the key till a second hyphen (“-”) symbol  is found. */
        public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {
            String sOne = new String(b1);
            String sTwo = new String(b2);

            // return new Character((char)b1[0]).compareTo((char)b2[0]);
            return sOne.substring(0, sOne.indexOf('-', 4)).compareTo(
                    sTwo.substring(0, sTwo.indexOf('-', 4)));
        }

        public int compare(Text o1, Text o2) {
            return compare(o1.getBytes(), 0, o1.getLength(), o2.getBytes(), 0,
                    o2.getLength());
        }
    }
```

*

> Then i am in need of sorting the keys based on  in key using
>   KeyComparator.

*

The api conveys the message that
setOutputKeyComparator  can be used in conjunction to simulate secondary sort on values.
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobConf.html

My expected Input to **Reducer**

```
Key - TAG-windows-QUE 
Value - 1241-QUE,1-QUE,4369-VIEWS,1-VIEWS
```

So that I can output the following from my Reducer

```
Key - TAG-windows Value - QUE-1242, VIEWS-4370
```

I tried the following **KeyComparator**. But I am unable to achieve my expected output

```
public static class KeyComparator extends WritableComparator {
    public KeyComparator() {
        super(Text.class);
    }

    public int compare(byte[] b1, int s1, int l1, byte[] b2, int s2, int l2) {

        int hypen = '-';
        int s1Ind = 0;
        int s2Ind = 0;
        for (int i = 4; i < b1.length; i++) {
            if (b1[i] == hypen) {
                s1Ind = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 4; i < b2.length; i++) {
            if (b2[i] == hypen) {
                s2Ind = i;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (s1Ind == 0 || s2Ind == 0)
            System.out.println(s1Ind + "<->" + s2Ind);

        int compare = compareBytes(b1, s1, s1Ind, b2, s2, s2Ind);
        if (compare == 0) {
            return compareBytes(b1, s1Ind + 1, l1 - s1Ind + 2, b2,
                    s2Ind + 1, l2 - s2Ind + 2);             
        }
        return compare;
    }
}
```

*Need help from hadoop mapreduce experts out here.*

Answer (score 1):

I found the following two links in stackoverflow that are relevant to my question.

[Secondary sorting in Map-Reduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188971/secondary-sorting-in-map-reduce)

[MapReduce (secondary) sorting / filtering - how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505735/mapreduce-secondary-sorting-filtering-how)

Let me try my luck out.